# Select option choice from form

Tags: javascript, iframe, frames

I am working on a project using iframes.  The last issue I am having is trying to access the value of the dropdown menu.  Now I know normally to access the value I would use this code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

My problem is since I have to access it from the forms I thought I could use this:

```
var e = path.type.value;
dropChoice = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

However it is not working.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What's path? What's type? What's value if it isn't a string (since a string wouldn't have an options property). (Being in a form wouldn't stop you getting an element by its ID)

Comment: Sorry path is a variable where I stored parent.frames[0].as5.  This path gets me to the form as5.  From there type is the name of the select menu.  I tried to get the element by that was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had tried this earlier but I guess not since it does now work.

```
dropChoice = path.instittype.value;
```